# cors headers are missing in ajax response, existing in browser response

Tags: angular, apache, nginx, tomcat9

I have an angular app which does a cross-origin GET request. The infrastructure is like this:

```
browser --- nginx --- apache --- tomcat9
```

When I look up the page by url in the browser, it contains the following headers, as evidenced by firefox's network debugger:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

However when the same page got accessed by the angular app, the above headers are missing from the response. This is the case both when I access the app from localhost, when I access it from an other host, and when I access it from the same host (in the latter case of course it works, but the headers are not there).

What does the difference, and how can I get the same behaviour?
Yes, I could add the headers in nginx and apache, but it is application-specific, I do not want to put it to the infrastructure.

The headers are emitted by the tomcat application by this code:

```
@WebFilter()
public class ResponseFilter implements Filter {

  private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
  private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
  private static final String VALUE = "*";
  private static final String CORS_HEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
      final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpServletResponse.setHeader(
        CORS_HEADER, VALUE);
    httpServletResponse.setHeader(
        ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, CONTENT_TYPE);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

The relevant part of the Apache config:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
<LocationMatch /.*>
#    DirectoryIndex off
    RewriteEngine Off
    AuthType openid-connect
    AllowOverride None
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

The relevant part of the nginx config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_tokens off;
      server_name  <server name>;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_certificate <filename>; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key <filename>; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;

location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://<ip address>:<port>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep the answer in the hope it will help someone overlooking the same thing as me.

The request failed as Unauthorized, the lack of cors headers was just added on top of it.

Authentication is handled by Apache, the request did not even got to tomcat, hence no cors headers.